# Font embedding error PDFA/1a iText 5.5.6

Tags: java, itext, pdfa

I have a class given below which is giving me Exception: `Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: ZapfDingbats`
I have the `ZapfDingbats` font embedded but I am still getting this `Exception`.
What i am trying to achieve here is create a `list` with a `bullet` in front of every `item` in the `list`.
What am i missing here?

```
public class SquareBullet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, XMPException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("list.pdf"), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfAWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);
        writer.setRunDirection(PdfAWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        writer.setTagged(PdfAWriter.markAll);
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        XmpWriter xmp = writer.getXmpWriter();

        DublinCoreProperties.addSubject(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Subject");
        DublinCoreProperties.setTitle(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Title", "en_US", "en_US");
        DublinCoreProperties.setDescription(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Description", "en_US", "en_US");
        PdfProperties.setKeywords(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "Keywords");
        PdfProperties.setVersion(xmp.getXmpMeta(), "1.4");
        document.addLanguage("en_US");
        document.open();
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS, BaseFont.ZAPFDINGBATS, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
        Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
        writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
        List list = new List(10);
        list.setListSymbol(new Chunk(String.valueOf((char)110), font));
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 1", font1)));
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 2", font1)));
        list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Test 3", font1)));
        document.add(list);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim *I have the ZapfDingbats font embedded* is wrong.

Granted, you define the font like this:

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS,
    BaseFont.ZAPFDINGBATS, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
```

As you use `BaseFont.EMBEDDED`, you might assume that the font will be embedded, **but it isn't.** You can check this by using that font in any other PDF that isn't PDF/A: if you go to *Document Properties > Fonts*, you'll see that the font isn't embedded.

**Why is this?**

There are 14 special fonts in PDF. We refer to them as the *Standard Type 1 fonts*. Every PDF viewer should be able to render text that uses those fonts, hence these fonts don't need to be embedded: 4 Helvetica fonts (regular, bold, italic, bold-italic), 4 Times Roman fonts (regular, bold, italic, bold-italic), 4 Courier fonts (regular, bold, italic, bold-italic), Symbol and Zapfdingbats.

iText ships with the AFM files of these fonts. AFM stands for *Adobe Font Metrics* and the files contain data about the widths, bounding boxes, and other metrics of glyphs that are available in each font.

The actual description of the *shape* of these fonts isn't shipped with iText. These are stored in a PFB (Printer Font Binary) file. Without these PFB files, iText can't (and won't) embed these Standard Type 1 fonts.

**In other words:** iText ignores the `BaseFont.EMBEDDED` parameter.

This is documented on many places. If you want to create PDF/A, you need font files, such as TTF, OTF, TTC files, or a combination of AFM and PFB files.

Comment: Understood. Thanks Bruno for such a detailed response.

Comment: @avinashchavan Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 0):

old thread, but for reference for those who came here, a note: PDF form fields do not work with PDF-A ... if PDF-A is omitted, then the error message to "ZapfDingbats" also disappears

Comment: *"PDF form fields do not work with PDF-A"* - that is not correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you must add the "jasperreports-fonts-" jar to your classpath.

Comment: The question does not appear JasperReports related at all.